# Select one Form Checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I've an HTML form that I've put together...

There is a question "Can you attend?" with a "Yes" and "No" checkbox.

Obviously who submits the form will either attend or not, so I would like for the form to only allow one checkbox to be selected of the two.

Here's the HTML:

```
<p>Can you attend?</p>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="attendance" value="checkbox" id="Yes" />
    Yes</label> 
        <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="attendance" value="checkbox" id="No" />
    No</label>
```

What does my code need to be? I'm guessing some JavaScript?

Thank you

Comment: does it have to be a checkbox? you can easily do this with some radio buttons. no javascript necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

And thus the radio was born :-)

```
<p>Can you attend?</p>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="checkbox" id="Yes" />
    Yes</label> 
        <label>
    <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="checkbox" id="No" />
    No</label>
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/oreped/